# Display divs with class as dropdown using js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to display these items that are being pulled onto a page via an api pull as a dropdown list instead of divs.

```
<div class="student"><a href="#">Joe Dullah</a></div>
<div class="student"><a href="#">Sarah Jenkins</a></div>
<div class="student"><a href="#">Cay Holton</a></div>
<div class="student"><a href="#">Alex Poe</a></div>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: can you share response from api?  is it array of values?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could append an `select` element dinamically and append every `a` element to it, see following please:

```js
$(function() {
    var $select = $('<select />');
    $(this).find('a').each(function() {
        var $option = $('<option />');
        $option.attr('value', $(this).attr('href')).html($(this).html());
        $select.append($option);
    });
    $("#list").replaceWith($select);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="list">
  <div class="student"><a href="#">Joe Dullah</a></div>
  <div class="student"><a href="#">Sarah Jenkins</a></div>
  <div class="student"><a href="#">Cay Holton</a></div>
  <div class="student"><a href="#">Alex Poe</a></div>
</div>
```

I hope it helps you, bye.